# Linux не определяет клавиатуру

Tags: linux, клавиатура

У меня старый комп, надо поставить на него linux или хотя бы потестить в лайф режиме. Но когда я загружаюсь с флешки не определяется клавиатура что бы что то нажать а таймера нету по которому он сам стартует. Что можно придумать? У меня две клавиатуры и обе не определяются.

Comment: Какой именно линукс грузишь? Ссылку на iso и модель матери.

Comment: @donRumata Debian 10, сейчас модель материнки сказать не могу, комп в разобранном состоянии, сутра или ближе к обеду соберу потом отпишусь

Comment: Ну так на матери должна быть написана модель и ревизия.

Comment: @donRumata вот по системной плате https://pastebin.com/hdJaKNAd

Comment: Не верю, что железо 10-и летней давности не видится на уровне дров. Тем более - там есть PS/2.

Answer (score 0):

По комменту:
Поставьте не 64, поставьте подходящее и тестировочное подходящее - все есть на всякие нужды. А ubuntu ставится на вообще задохлые, а если и это будет тяжеловато, то можно найти и что еще полегче из линуксового семейства/сборок.

Установите, а не загружайтесь.

И потом - для теста компа не обязательно линукс изначально - используйте готовые сборки и решения на основе LiveCD, BootCD PE x64, Hiren's BootCD (HBCD) и подобное, что запускается и работает с флешки и позволяет все тестировать и, при необходимости - обслуживать и вносить изменения.

Comment: Я debian 10 live и качал, что бы загрузится потестить и установить

Comment: И кстати комп старый, проц 2008 года и всего 2гб оперативки, я плохо разбираюсь но разве х64 на таких компах работает?

Answer (score 0):

добавьте таймаут в загрузочное меню и пункт по умолчанию livecd

нужно поправить файлы menu.cfg и/или txt.cfg

Comment: А это в .iso файле надо делать или уже когда на флешку запишу?

Comment: проще на флэшке поправить